# Create half circle background drawable with transparent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I try to create like this drawable

[image]

I wrote code and almost working correctly

```
public class GetsugaDrawable extends Drawable {

private final Context context;
private final float radiusScale = 1.2f;
private final float yOffset = 0.3f;

private final int colorLower = Color.RED;
private final int colorUpper = Color.BLACK;

private final Paint upperPaint = new Paint();

public GetsugaDrawable(Context c) {
    context = c;
    upperPaint.setColor(colorUpper);
    upperPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
}

@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    final Rect bounds = new Rect(getBounds());
    canvas.drawColor(colorLower, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
    final float radius = radiusScale * bounds.height();
    final int x = bounds.centerX();
    final float y = (bounds.centerY() - bounds.height() * yOffset) - radius;
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, upperPaint);
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    // ignored TODO impl.
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {
    // ignored TODO impl.
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
}
}
```

Here is my result

[image]

I tried to change

```
    private final int colorUpper = Color.BLACK;
```

with

```
    private final int colorUpper = Color.TRANSPARENT;
```

but when I run my app again with transparent color, the result is like this

[image]

What am i doing wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: The correct solution is using shapes, not drawing manually: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: Problem in your code, that you're drawing transparent circle OVER red background. Definitely, nothing will change. You should draw pixels and don't draw transparent areas.

Comment: where are you using this GetsugaDrawable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create half circle background in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338046/create-half-circle-background-in-android)

Comment: In LinearLayout background @Ankita

Comment: Show the code where are you setting background.

Comment: Also see this: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add upperPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

```
public class GetsugaDrawable extends Drawable {
private final Context context;
private final float radiusScale = 1.2f;
private final float yOffset = 0.3f;

private final int colorLower = Color.RED;
private final int colorUpper = Color.BLACK;

private final Paint upperPaint = new Paint();

public GetsugaDrawable(Context c) {
    context = c;
    upperPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    upperPaint.setColor(colorUpper);
    upperPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));      
}

@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    final Rect bounds = new Rect(getBounds());
    canvas.drawColor(colorLower);
    final float radius = radiusScale * bounds.height();
    final int x = bounds.centerX();
    final float y = (bounds.centerY() - bounds.height() * yOffset) - radius;
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, upperPaint);
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {

}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {

}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
}}
```

And don't forget to view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null); on target view

Answer (score 0):

You can change `draw` function.

```
@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    final Rect bounds = new Rect(getBounds());
    final float radius = radiusScale * bounds.height();
    final int x = bounds.centerX();
    final float y = (bounds.centerY() - bounds.height() * yOffset) - radius;
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(x, y, radius, CW);
    canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
    canvas.drawColor(colorLower);
}
```

Try this.